# Listing and Loading Nodes with AJAX

Tags: nodes, ajax

In Drupal 7
I want to make a view of

```
/------------------------  
--------- Header --------  
List of links to nodes

/-------------
Node content
```

When the links of nodes in Header clicked, the node content should be loaded by ajax.
Is there anyway to do this by Views? or do I need some custom PHP?

Answer (score 0):

First off if the content is only text and its size is not very big I recommend you strongly not to use Ajax , unless you can do it using views in the following way:

Be sure to enable the Ajax in views:

[image]

now this code will load the view.

```
$("links_click").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'view_name='+your_view&'view_display_id='+view_display_id,
                success: function(response) {
                  var output = response[1].data;
                  $(".your_container").html(output);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('An error occured!');
                }
              });
        });
```

for more detail visit [this link](http://wearepropeople.com/blog/drupal-views-ajax).

Comment: Your effort is appreciated.. First, this didn't work when setting AJAX to Yes. Second, I want to list the titles (linkable) at the top.